# Getting Tag Names with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
source_code = """<a href="#" name="linkName">ok</a>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code)
print soup.a.? #find the object name
```

Using the code displayed above, i am trying to print the anchor tags 'name' which is `linkName` but i'm not sure which module or object i will be using, i have tried `contents`,`name` and `tag_name_re`.

Can anybody help me out? thanks!

Comment: Did you `print soup.a`?

Comment: yes, it printed `<a href="#" name="linkName">ok</a>`.

i will give `soup.a['name']` a go!

Comment: Ok well that worked, you're more than welcome to use it as an answer as i can't answer my own question for another 8 hours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already answered your question.

```
soup.a['name']
```

**Edit**

If you have more than one `a` element, you can do this:

```
x = """<x><a name="foo"/><a name="bar"/></x>"""
s = bs4.BeautifulSoup(x)
for a in s.findChildren("a"):
    print(a["name"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
source_code = """<a href="#" name="linkName"><i><b>ok</b></i></a>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code)
for tag in soup.findChildren():
    print tag.name
```

findChildren() function will return a list which possess all the children tag.

```
[<a href="#" name="linkName"><i><b>ok</b></i></a>, <i><b>ok</b></i>, <b>ok</b>]
```

Then iterate the list to get each tag name.

```
  Output
    a
    i
    b
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation text for OP to understand your code? Thanks

Comment: @Paco , Thanks for your valuable feedback, now I have updated my answer.