# getting tag names at one level with Beautifulsoup for XML

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Related to this: [Getting Tag Names with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559191/getting-tag-names-with-beautifulsoup)

I have an XML document, and I want to get all of the tags at a single level - so parsing

```
<parent>
    <child>
    </child>
</parent>  
<parent2>
</parent2>
```

would return `['parent', 'parent2']`. How can I do this? using

```
for tag in document.findChildren():
    print tag.name
```

gives

```
['parent', 'child', 'parent2']
```

which is undesired.

Comment: Use [`.children`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children).

Comment: My mistake, edited question

Comment: .children returns `['None', 'Parent', 'None]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`recursive`](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/docs/ios/beautifulsoup_ref.html) keyword

```
for tag in document.findChildren(recursive=False):
    print tag.name
```